# Git Flow integration with Redmine issues

Tags: git, redmine, git-flow, issue-tracking

is there a way to link issues from redmine to the git server using Git Flow? i would like to be able to close issues automatically when i finish the feature with git-flow

Comment: What do you mean? Git flow is a command for *git*. You don't integrate the command with Redmine, you integrate *git*. Just google for "git redmine integration"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Redmine at a level that I could give you a definite answer.

If you can close issues through an API from CLI, [git-flow AVH edition](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh) can do the task of closing the issue.

git-flow AVH edition has hooks and filters for all commands which means you can run a script when you run `git flow feature finish` which can close an issue.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of git-flow AVH Edition. git-flow AVH edition is backwards compatible with the original git-flow.